# Unable to confirm Google credentials for `Gmailr` when running via Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: r, windows-task-scheduler, gmailr

I'm trying to schedule an R script to run through Windows Task Scheduler, and I'd like this script to send an automated email through `gmailr` when it has finished running. Currently, I have the task scheduled to run in Task Scheduler, and it will run and save output into a folder. The file path for the output directory contains the run date, so I know that the script is running as scheduled. The problem is that the email isn't sent after the output is saved.

To troubleshoot, I've run the script manually in RStudio, and it runs successfully. The output is saved, and the email will be sent through `gmailr`. This makes me think the code is ok and that I have some sort of higher-level authentication issue when running a non-interactive session.

When I look at Task Scheduler, the "Last Run Result" for the task is "Incorrect function. (0x800700001)." I've saved the error log when running this script through Task Scheduler, and it contains:

```r
"Error: Can't get Google credentials.
Are you running gmailr in a non-interactive session? Consider:
  * Call `gm_auth()` directly with all necessary specifics.
Execution halted"
```

After systematically attempting to run the script through Task Scheduler when certain lines of code are missing, the error message appears to be due to `gm_auth(cache = here(".secret"), email = "[SENDER_EMAIL]")`

I've included a reprex of my code below.

```r
here::i_am("[PROJ_DIR]/test-automated-email.R")

library(tidyverse)
library(here)
library(glue)
library(gmailr)
library(gargle)

pass_body <- glue("Everything worked great!")

gm_auth_configure(path = here("[MY_JSON_FILE]"))
gm_auth(cache = here(".secret"), email = "[SENDER_EMAIL]")

email <- gm_mime() %>%
  gm_from("[SENDER_EMAIL]") %>%
  gm_to("[RECIPIENT_EMAIL]") %>%
  gm_subject("Success") %>%
  gm_html_body(pass_body)
gm_send_message(email)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Some other (hopefully helpful) info:

- I have the same issue when I hard code the working directory and avoid using the `here` package's functions
- I've saved the working directory and the contents of the working directory to a log file when running via Task Scheduler, and the cache and .json files are present. This makes me think I'm pointing to the correct path in `gm_auth_configure()` and `gm_auth()`.
- The .json file is an OAuth file
- I've tried as many possible combinations of the parameters for `gm_auth()` and `gm_auth_configure()` that I can think of (e.g., `gm_auth_configure(path = "[MY_JSON_FILE]")`), but I still have the same issue regardless of the combination.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to resolve this? Any and all help is appreciated!

Thanks!